# Does somebody know if it is allowed to gather Information about Instagram stories?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram, screen-scraping

Does somebody know if it is allowed to gather Information about Instagram stories? (in an automated way, maybe automated via API) 
such as what was written in the story?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Instagram's Platform Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/). For example: "Only store or cache User Content for the period necessary to provide your app's service."

Comment: Allowed by who? The government? Instagram? Your parents?

Comment: @showdev thank you! do you know if its regulated in which way you are gathering the informations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. Everything thats public (that anyone can see).
You can do that with python lib called `Instaloader`